# What does the phrase "Crash was epic" mean?

Tags: meaning-in-context, sentence-meaning

The scene is in the office in a film.

A character says

> "Crash was epic".

What does this sentence mean?

Comment: If he appeared in a film of that name, it's almost certainly the film that is being referred to.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have correctly understood the sentence.  It is natural to refer to movies (or plays, books etc) by their titles:

> *Crash* was epic. *Finding Dory* made me cry. *Star Wars: A New Hope* changed my life.

In text, this can be suggested by writing the title in italics (or underlining).  In speech, you depend on context.  But in this film, the context is given by the reference to Ryan Phillippe.